# SparkStreaming: Retrieve message from Kafka and write to HDFS as binary

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I get non serializable exception when attempting to retrieve and write the value into HDFS using `RDD.saveAsObjectFile(targetHDFSDir)`.  I wanted to be able to read binary (bytearray) and write as binary (bytearray).

```
Key and Value deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

>

```
  val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
    org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG -> bootStrapServer,
    org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG -> "Spark1",
    org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer",
    org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer",
    org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG -> "earliest",
    org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG -> "false",
    org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG -> "PLAINTEXT"
    )
```

Comment: Can you share consumer's properties?

Comment: Please find above